# How can I implement useEffect without repeated mounting and unmounting?

Tags: reactjs, state, use-effect

I am wondering if there is a better way to achieve the same thing as below. This code works but it forces this useEffect to mount and un-mount a few times before it can make it through the if statement, which is not ideal.

I have a useEffect like below...

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("setNames mounted")
    if (devices !== null && deviceNames !== null){
        setNames(trueDeviceNames(devices.devices, deviceNames.values))
    }
    return ()=> {
        console.log("setNames un-mounted")
    }
}, [devices, deviceNames])
```

I have 2 other useEffects that fetch data and setDevices and setDeviceNames. I don't want to run THIS useEffect until they have completed their fetches and are no longer null. My code works but surely there is a cleaner way to achieve this?

Comment: This is totally fine, it's meant to reset itself. You could remove the unmount (useless) function. If `trueDeviceNames` isn't computation heavy, you could even remove the state altogether and just call it within the render phase. e.g. `<span>{trueDeviceNames(devices.devices, deviceNames.values)}</span>`

Comment: Interesting. I figured there was a cleaner way to do this because the useEffect gets called every time my dependencies change. However, only the state is set when the conditional is met. The issue is that if I have many useEffects getting called but not getting through the conditional it might cause performance issues from unnecessary mounting and unmounting, or weird side effects.

Comment: There's also useMemo which might be more appropriate than state in this case, coupled with your optimized dependencies (in your other comment)

Answer (score 1):

useEffect mount and unmount is on the half of `[devices, deviceNames]` shallow comparison, so the function call is caused by the change of devices or deviceNames. you may want to consider those values for optimizing your useEffects.

your useEffect will not cause your component re-render until both devices are deviceNames are in-equal to null.

**Note**
Shallow comparison use reference check for objects ant will pass true every time they change.

e.g.

```js
shallowEqual({value: '1'},  {value: 1}) // false
shallowEqual({value: 1},  {value: 1}) // false
shallowEqual({value:'1'},  {value: '1'}) // false

shallowEqual('1', '1') // true
shallowEqual(1, 1}) // true
shallowEqual('1',  1) // false '1' !== 1
```

so you can optimize your useEffect by more precise dependencies array

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("setNames mounted")
    if (devices !== null && deviceNames !== null){
        setNames(trueDeviceNames(devices.devices, deviceNames.values))
    }
    return ()=> {
        console.log("setNames un-mounted")
    }
}, [devices && devices.devices, deviceNames && deviceNames.values])
```

or if you are sure that devices and deviceNames are callable you can write the cleaner version

```js
[devices.devices, deviceNames.values])
```

These will only update by exact value change and prevent lots of re-renders

If you want to call useEffect only on both value existence you can add dependencies like following

```js
[Boolean(devices) && Boolean(deviceNames)]
```

this will be false until both have truthy value and call useEffect at most 2 times on startup scenario

Comment: I appreciate the comment but I think you misunderstand my question. However it did lead me to a better solution. For dependencies use [devices && deviceNames]. This ensures it wont render until both are no longer null. Simple. Thank you

Comment: I'm happy that you find a solution, but this dep array can cause multiple run imaging in the following scenario. first, both are null (1st call) then deviceNames get its actual value, and (2nd call) then devices get its value, and (3rd call). These are all based on not changing these object reference (doing something like memoization)